# UICollectionView inside UITableView passing data with Alamofire

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, alamofire, swifty-json

So I have a TableView and inside the first cell I've putted a UICollectionView.
I'm using Alamofire and SwiftyJSON for getting the data and then passing them into an array. Inside the cellForRow function I'm passing the first array into an array inside the TableView's Cell and then passing it to the CollectionView's Cell.
But the problem is that the TableView's functions runs before Alamofire finishes and therefore it will pass an empty array.
How I should run Alamofire before everything?

The **First Controller** where I'm using Alamofire:

```
class DiscoverController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource  {

 // MARK: -- TOP Books
    var topBooks = [Book]()
    @IBOutlet weak var discoverBooksTable: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        discoverBooksTable.isHidden = true
        bookHTTP(url: "https://api.example.com/top/book")
    }


   // MARK: -- TableView Configuration
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let topBookCell = discoverBooksTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "topBooksCell") as! TopBooksCell
       topBookCell.bookCollections.append(contentsOf: topBooks)
        return topBookCell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 140
    }


    // MARK: -- Alamofire
    func bookHTTP(url:String) {
        Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
            if ((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
                let booksData = JSON(responseData.result.value!)
                if booksData["request_cached"] == true {
                    print("⚠️ \(booksData["request_cached"].boolValue)")
                    if let booksDATA = booksData["top"].array {
                        for bookItems in booksDATA {
                            self.topBooks.append(Book(id: bookItems["b_id"].intValue, title: bookItems["title"].stringValue, type: bookItems["type"].stringValue, bookItems["series"].intValue, bookItems["url"].stringValue, bookItems["image_url"].stringValue, bookItems["rank"].intValue))



                        }
                    self.discoverBooksTable.isHidden = false
                    self.discoverBooksTable.reloadData()
                    }
                }

                for i in self.topBooks {
                    print(" \(i.title ?? "N/A")")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the **TopBookCell** File:

```
class TopBookCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var topBooksCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    // Book collection array
    var bookCollections = [Book]()

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        print(bookCollections)

    }

    // MARK: -- CollectionView Configuration
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return bookCollections.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let topBookCol = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "topBooksCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! TopBooksCollectionCell
        topBookCol.topBookCover.kf.setImage(with: URL(string: bookCollections[indexPath.row].image_url!))

        return topBookCol
    }



    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

and inside **TopBooksCollectionCell** I have a IBOutlet for UIImageView

**GITHUB**: https://github.com/iarata/UICollectionViewInsideUITableView

Comment: just reload tableview on response

Comment: @SPatel inside the Alamofire function I'm reloading tableview after "for bookItems in booksDATA {..}" doesn't work

Comment: `run Alamofire` is not possible alamofire run your request and request is totaly base on network condition

Comment: @SPatel okay so how should I confirm to Alamofire and then if it's finished I load the tableview and everything else?

Comment: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell:UITableviewCell indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let topBookCell = cell as? TopBooksCell else { return }
       topBookCell.bookCollections = topBooks
       topBookCell.collectionView.reloadData()
        return topBookCell
    }

Comment: other solution, var bookCollections = [Book](){ didSet { self.collectionView.reloadData() } }

Comment: @SPatel THX A LOT! the first answer kind of didn't work (private func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { let topAnimeCell = cell as? TopBooksCell
        topBooksCell!.bookCollections = topBooks
        topBooksCell?.topBooksCollectionView.reloadData()
        return topBooksCell! } but the second one worked!

Comment: don't use private its tableview's delegate method

Comment: without private: (Instance method 'tableView(_:willDisplay:forRowAt:)' nearly matches optional requirement 'tableView(_:willDisplay:forRowAt:)' of protocol 'UITableViewDelegate') also still didn't work

Comment: set collectionview cell size

Comment: if possible create demo project in gitgub

Comment: @SPatel https://github.com/iarata/UICollectionViewInsideUITableView